# XCode: Objective C: Multiple View in UIPageViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am making a simple magazine app and trying it with the UIPageViewController.

My plan is to have animation on each page and user interaction.

I have managed to view all the pages with different images in each page but i know it is just a viewer because it only has one view which is a UIImageView with a series of array with it.

What i want is to have different viewControllers so that i can add other functionalities on it and also adding some buttons.

I am working on the Page-Based App of the new XCode.

Is it possible??

Comment: That is not what a page-based app is meant for, i think you need to look at a navigation/tabbar based application.

Comment: but i need the pageCurl like iBook effect on the page-based app.

Comment: You can make any page do a pageCurl effect, not only the page-based app.

Comment: I believe you can make it curl to any and all directions you wish.